# Load and use echarts.format in Angular 6

Tags: angular, echarts

I am trying to adapt an echarts component to work in an angular 6 dashboard.  I have added echarts and ngx-echarts to the project via npm.

In that example they load a function `formatUtil = echarts.format`.  I can (attempt to) load the equivalent library by importing echarts like so:

```
import { format } from 'echarts';
```

In my main class I have

```
formatUtil: new format;
```

Later on in my code I have a call to the formatter function to build a tooltip:

```
  tooltip: {
        formatter: function (info) {
          var value = info.value;
          var treePathInfo = info.treePathInfo;
          var treePath = [];

          for (var i = 1; i < treePathInfo.length; i++) {
            treePath.push(treePathInfo[i].name);
          }

          return [
            '<div class="tooltip-title">' + this.formatUtil.encodeHTML(treePath.join('/')) + '</div>',
            'Revenue: $' + this.formatUtil.addCommas(value) ,
          ].join('');
        }
      },
```

When I mouseover the tooltip, I get the following error:

```
zone.js:195 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatUtil' of undefined
    at formatter (treemap.component.ts:98)
    at ExtendedClass._showTooltipContent (TooltipView.js:544)
    at ExtendedClass.<anonymous> (TooltipView.js:479)
    at util.js:424
    at ExtendedClass._showOrMove (TooltipView.js:356)
    at ExtendedClass._showSeriesItemTooltip (TooltipView.js:478)
    at ExtendedClass._tryShow (TooltipView.js:336)
    at ExtendedClass.<anonymous> (TooltipView.js:158)
    at Object.handler (util.js:424)
    at doEnter (globalListener.js:113)
```

The example in question is here:

https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=treemap-show-parent

Can anyone advise the best way to adapt the `echarts.format` function so that I can call it in my angular component?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I've managed to solve it by importing the echart namespace and cast it to any.

First I've imported the namespace:

```
import * as echarts from 'echarts'
```

Then I declared a variable:

```
formatUtil: any = (<any>echarts).format;
```

After that I was able to use it.